# Popup MVC 4 partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm tried to popup partial view . but its not working , not hit the controller method as well.
this is my code.

script:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    $("#cusCreate").live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        debugger;
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $("#dialog-edit").dialog({
            type:"GET",
            title: 'Add Customert',
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            height: 355,
            width: 400,
            show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
            modal: true,
            draggable: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                alert(url);
                $(this).load(url);
            },
            close: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        });

        $("#dialog-edit").dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

View :

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", "Customer", null, new { @id = "cusCreate" })
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create(int? id)
    {
        db.customers = null;

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView("_Create", db.customers);
        }
        else
        {
            return View(db.customers);
        }
       // return View();
    }
```

Partial view think it is a noraml one...

Comment: remove ` e.preventDefault();`

Comment: do you get alert with the required URL ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to include jQuery unobtrusive Ajax in order to have Request.IsAjaxRequest return true from an ajax request.Add http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.1/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js to your page. Or add the NuGet package http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/

Comment: keep in mind IsAjax does not carry over with a RedirectToAction